# Matching second last word in sentence through regular expression?

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a way to match the second last word on a line, such as this:

```
123 Smith St Melbourne VIC 3000
```

I'd like to match just "`VIC`". Does someone have a regex I can use?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What have you tried so far? :)

Comment: What language/tool are you using? What is a word for you? Only alphanumeric or any character that is not a space, or ???

Answer (score 1):

Depending of what is a "word" for you, you can use:

- A word is 1 or more characters that is not a space

  - `\S+(?=\h+\S+$)` will match 1 or more not space followed by 1 or more horizontal space then 1 or more non space
- A word is 1 or more alphabetic character

  - `[a-zA-Z]+(?=\h+[a-zA-Z]+$)`
- A word is 1 or more alphanumeric character

  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=\h+[a-zA-Z0-9]+$)`
- A word is 1 or more any letter in any language

  - `\pL+(?=\h+\pL+$)`
- A word is 1 or more any letter or digit in any language

  - `[\pL\pN]+(?=\h+[\pL\pN]+$)`

Comment: What flavor of regex are you using? Looks like Perl, that is *very far* from common...

Comment: @vonbrand: PCRE, many languages and tools are using it.

Answer (score 0):

To **match** the second word from the end use: `(?!(\w+\s\w+$))|(?:.+?)`

To **replace** everything other than the second last word use: `(?!(\w+\s\w+$))(?:.+?)`

You might need to do something about special characters you may have, though.